# Unable to access scope property in directive

Tags: angularjs, combobox

I'm building a combobox plugin in Angular, and I'm at a point where I'm getting all sorts of weird behaviors I can't figure out. Here's one of them:

I have one directive (called linksEdit) that contains within it comboboxes. In the link function of the linksEdit directive, I set the following array:

```
scope.levels = [
    { 'id': 'link', 'value': 'Link'},
    { 'id': 'affiliate', 'value': 'Affiliate'},
    { 'id': 'partner', 'value': 'Partner'},
];
```

In that directive, I have the combobox directive, passing the levels value:

```
<combobox data="levels" value="cb_value" search="data.level" strict></combobox>
```

And combobox does have an isolate scope:

```
scope: {
    'data': '=data',
    'search': '=search',
    'value': '=value',
}
```

I have code in the combobox that sets the default value of the combobox based on what data.level is. The linksEdit directive is called once (with the new attribute set) and then is being repeated with ng-repeat (to show existing data). I added two console.logs at the beginning of my combobox directive:

```
console.log(scope);
console.log(scope.data);
```

For the first instance of linksEdit (not in the repeat), scope.data has the data I expect. In the ng-repeat, scope shows my data property, but scope.data comes up as undefined. I'm not sure why they're behaving so differently.

Comment: does `data.level` come from ajax? How it is populated?

Comment: `data.level` is set by AJAX, but that shouldn't affect `levels`, should it? I realize now that my choice of variable names is a bit confusing in this particular case.

Comment: link will get load as directive controller gets loaded..you need to use watch `scope.$watch('data', function(n){ if(n.length> 0)//you could should be here })`

Comment: But even then, why would it not have data that is instantiated in the parent controller? As I mentioned, `levels` is a hard-coded value, and it shows up when I dump scope, but accessing it directly is the problem.